# Why many fonts don't work with ffmpeg subtitles?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, fonts

I simply want to hardcode some subtitles. While standard fonts work well, when I search disk and apply others from `Font` catalog, they rarely works in this way:

```
-vf "subtitles=subb.srt:fontsdir=CopperplateGothicStd-33BC.otf:force_style='FontName=CopperplateGothicStd-33BC, ...
```

I get info: `[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 000000000286fec0] fontselect: (CopperplateGothicStd-33BC, 400, 0) -> ArialMT, 0, ArialMT` abd program just cast it to Arial. Sometimes I get message `glyph not found` so I can understand it, but here don't know what an error is present. Someone has similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

`fontsdir=CopperplateGothicStd-33BC.otf`

You are specifying a font file. The `fontsdir` option requires a *path* (e.g. c:\myfonts\ ) not a file.